# Remove zero from ternary plot

Tags: python, plotly, axis-labels, ternary

I have the following plot and I want to remove the 0 in the origins.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px  
  
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatterternary({
    'mode': 'markers', 'a': [0.3],'b': [0.5], 'c': [0.6],
    'marker': {'color': 'AliceBlue','size': 14,'line': {'width': 2} },
                                  }))
fig.update_layout({
    'ternary': {
        'sum': 100,
        'aaxis': {'nticks':1, 'ticks':""},
        'baxis': {'nticks':1},
        'caxis': {'nticks':1}  }})

fig.update_traces( hovertemplate = "<b>CatA: %{a:.0f}<br>CatB: %{b:.0f}<br>CatC: %{c:.0f}<extra></extra>")
  
fig.show()
```

[image: Remove zero]

I am surprised because documentation [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/ternary/) says the minimum of `nticks` is 1, not 0 (which does not work). How can I remove the 0 from the corners?

[image: Documentation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as u mentioned doc says ntick specifies the maximum number of ticks for the particular axis.
So its true, cannot be zero.

```
fig.update_ternaries(aaxis_showticklabels=False)
fig.update_ternaries(baxis_showticklabels=False)
fig.update_ternaries(caxis_showticklabels=False)
```